# encode string in PHP as a=1,b=2 and so on

Tags: php

I want to create PHP function to encode any string just with following rule.

> a=1; b=2; c=3;.....y=25;z=26;

for eg.
   If my string is "**abc**" then my encoded data will be "**123**".

We can use `$key=>$value` array but it will iterate 26 times for every letter!!

Comment: Then what if your string is "by" and it will encode in 225 then it will hard to understand actual sting again.Whether it is "by" or "bbe" so not use such type of method

Comment: Rather use some delimiter to identify different characters.

Comment: I would rather use a unique key for each char and all keys with the same length

Comment: yes that's right. I just wanted to convert albhabates to number! thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some delimiter so that you can identify separate characters. You can try this.

```
$chars = array('a' => 1, 'b' =>  2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);

$str = "acd";
$encoded = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
   $encoded[] = $chars[$str[$i]];
}

echo implode('|', $encoded);
```

**Output**

```
1|3|4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function encodedString($your_string)
    $alpha_arr =  range("A", "Z");

    $your_string = strtoupper($your_string);

    $encoded = "";

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($your_string); $i++)
    {
        $strOne = substr($your_string, $i, 1);
        if (in_array($strOne, $alpha_arr)) 
        {       
            $encoded .= array_search($strOne, $alpha_arr)+1;
        }   
    }
    return $encoded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ord()` method outputs the ascii value. now you can subtract 64 and 96 based on the text case to get the corresponding values. You will need no iterations or loop or anything. use a change case function and get the ascii value. the subtract the constant.

More details about **ord** method [here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/string-ord.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a padded encoding number to avoid confusions, with an array such as:

```
$converter = array('a' => '01', 'b' => '02' ...);
```

then go through each letter of the original string and construct your encoded string accessing the $converter array by key ('a', 'b' ... 'z').

you can also use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) to loop through the converter array and replace each character. Using str_replace you have at most N iterations, where N is the number of items in the converter array, regardless of the original string dimension.